Solving the system $5x+y=2$ and $13x+3y=1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{41}$
This is the problem I'm working on:

Solve, in $\mathbb{Z}_{41}$, the system of equations
\begin{aligned} 5 x + y &= 2 \\ 13 x + 3 y &= 1 \end{aligned}
Enter your answers as values between $0$ and $40$ for $x$ and $y$.
$x = \{\}$
$y = \{\}$

This is how I thought, however I get the wrong answer:
To solve the system of equations in $\mathbb{Z}_{41}$, we can use the method of Gaussian elimination.
First, let's rewrite the system of equations:
\begin{aligned}
5x + y &\equiv 2 \pmod{41} \\ 
13x + 3y &\equiv 1 \pmod{41} 
\end{aligned}
We can eliminate $y$ from the first equation by multiplying both sides of the first equation by $3$ and subtracting the second equation multiplied by $1$:
\begin{aligned} 
(5x + y) \cdot 3 &\equiv 2 \cdot 3 \pmod{41} \\ 
(13x + 3y) \cdot 1 &\equiv 1 \cdot 1 \pmod{41} 
\end{aligned}
This gives us:
\begin{aligned} 
15x + 3y &\equiv 6 \pmod{41} \\ 
13x + 3y &\equiv 1 \pmod{41} 
\end{aligned}
Subtracting the second equation from the first, we get:
\begin{aligned} 
15x - 13x &\equiv 6 - 1 \;\;\pmod{41} \\
2x &\equiv 5 \qquad\pmod{41} \\
x &\equiv 5 \cdot 2^{-1} \pmod{41}
\end{aligned}
The answer I get is:
$$x = 23 \qquad y = 28$$
What am I doing wrong?

When you multiply a congruence you also multiply the moduli: $a \equiv b \mod n \rightarrow ac \equiv bc \mod nc $

$x\equiv 23\Rightarrow y \equiv 2-5x\equiv 2-5(23)\equiv -113\equiv 10\ (\not\equiv \color{#c00}{28}).,$ We can' tell you where your error is in this computation since you don't show it. Please delete the question since questions based on such errors are of no use to others (you need to first unaccept the answer). @A.Person That is not relevant here.

From lst line $$\begin{aligned} 
15x - 13x &\equiv 6 - 1 \pmod{41} \\
2x &\equiv 5 \pmod{41} \\
2x &\equiv 5+41  \pmod{41}\\
x &\equiv 23  \pmod{41}\\x=41k+23\\
\end{aligned}$$then put it in one of equations (for example the first one)
$$\begin{aligned} 
5x+y &\equiv 2 \pmod{41} \\
5(41k+23)+y &\equiv 2 \pmod{41} \\
y+115 &\equiv 2  \pmod{41}\\
y &\equiv 2-115  \pmod{41}\\y &\equiv 2-115+3\times(41)  \pmod{41}\\y &\equiv 10  \pmod{41}\\y=41q+10
\end{aligned}$$so $$x=23\\y=10$$

Please don't answer (off-topic) questions based on arithmetic errors.

What happens in MSE when a downvote with the best answer sign appears lovingly married? Shouldn't there be a group of people responsible for ensuring that these crazy situations don't happen?

@BillDubuque At least it seems to me that you pointed out the arithmetic error of the original question after the answer had been posted

@JianingSong I don't understand the point of your remark,
